# Java reading in line separated by space and inserting into tree

Tags: java

I am trying to read in user input separated by space and insert the values into a tree. Everything is working correctly until I have double digit integers. It seems to be reading each integer char and inserting into the tree when I want it to read both first and then insert the double digit integer into the tree

e,g. when user inputs 9 3 + 7 * this works fine, however, when user input 10 3 + 7 *, it will insert 10 as 1 first and then insert 0. I want it to insert 10. (this is the prefix format of the eqn)

Here is what I have so far:

in my main class

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();
    System.out.println("\nEnter equation: ");
    et.buildTree(scan.nextLine());
}
```

in my buildTree method..

```
public void buildTree(String eqn){
    for(int i = 0; i <= eqn.legnth()-1; i++)
    insert(eqn.charAt(i));    //how to insert 10 instead of 1 and then 0??
}
```

I know that there is a problem in my buildTree method but I'm not sure what I need to do to read the double-digit character..

Full Code:

```
package expressiontreetest;

import java.util.Scanner;


class ExpressionTree {
class TreeNode {
    char data;
    TreeNode left, right;

    /** constructor **/
    public TreeNode(char data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
class StackNode {
    TreeNode treeNode;
    StackNode next;
    public StackNode(TreeNode treeNode) {
        this.treeNode = treeNode;
        next = null;
    }
}

private static StackNode top;
public ExpressionTree() {
    top = null;
}
public void clear() {
    top = null;
}
private void push(TreeNode ptr) {
    if (top == null) top = new StackNode(ptr);
    else {
        StackNode nptr = new StackNode(ptr);
        nptr.next = top;
        top = nptr;
    }
}
private TreeNode pop() {
    if (top == null) throw new RuntimeException("Underflow");
    else {
        TreeNode ptr = top.treeNode;
        top = top.next;
        return ptr;
    }
}
private TreeNode peek() {
    return top.treeNode;
}
private void insert(char val) {
    try {
        if (isDigit(val)) {
            TreeNode nptr = new TreeNode(val);
            push(nptr);
        }
        else if (isOperator(val)) {
            TreeNode nptr = new TreeNode(val);
            nptr.left = pop();
            nptr.right = pop();
            push(nptr);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
    }
}
    //if it is a valid digit return true
private boolean isDigit(char ch) {
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}
    //if it is a valid operator return true 
private boolean isOperator(char ch) {
    return ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/';
}

private int toDigit(char ch) {
    return ch - '0';
}

    //starting from index 0 increment the index after char has been inserted into the tree 
    //and terminate the for loop once we have reached equation legnth
public void buildTree(String eqn) {
//            String [] eqnSubparts = eqn.split(" ");
//          System.out.print("\neqnSubparts: " + eqnSubparts);

    for (int i = 0; i <= eqn.length() - 1; i++) {               
//                    System.out.print("\neqnSubparts: " + eqnSubparts[i]);
                    insert(eqn.charAt(i));   
            }
}

public double evaluate() {
    return evaluate(peek());
}

public double evaluate(TreeNode ptr) {
    if (ptr.left == null && ptr.right == null) return toDigit(ptr.data);
    else {
        double result = 0.0;
        double left = evaluate(ptr.left);
        double right = evaluate(ptr.right);
        char operator = ptr.data;
                    //switch statment for oper
        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            result = left + right;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = left - right;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = left * right;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = left / right;
            break;
        default:
            result = left + right;
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

}

/** class ExpressionTreeTest **/
public class ExpressionTreeTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Expression Tree Test");

    /** make object of ExpressionTree **/
    ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();

    System.out.println("\nEnter equation in prefix form");



            //String line = scan.nextLine();
            //System.out.print("First digit : " + line);
            et.buildTree(scan.nextLine());


    System.out.print("\nInput : ");

    System.out.println("\n\nEvaluated Result : " + et.evaluate());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there spaces between each set of character in the user input? In other words is it like 10 space 3 space + space 7. If not, try inputing in this format and then you can split the input on space

Comment: yes there are spaces in my user input, and the program works fine when i input only single digits

Comment: Please provide an answer for the question. I voted up but there is no answer .

Comment: In the builTree replace
 insert(eqn.charAt(i)); with insert(eqnSubparts[i]);

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your `buildTree()` method is that, you are iterating over each character of the equation, you have nowhere considered the spaces.
What you could instead do is, split the eqn around spaces using `String[] eqnSubparts = eqn.split(" ")` and then iterate over this array and insert each entry of array in your tree.
Note: If you also want to insert spaces in your tree then while iterating when you insert each entry of array, also insert a space.

Comment: i updated the question and added my full code. It seem like it will be hard to just change from char to string. I am getting an error when i try to convert it.

Comment: You can pass a string to your insert method & when you are passing the character to isDigit method, at that point you can iterate over each character of your string and pass. And when all the characters of your string satisfy then you call your operation in if/else block

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tokenize the string based on spaces ? Instead of using character by character approach, why don't you adopt a string by string approach. Use the split function in java.

```
split(" ")
```

This function returns an array of strings.

10 3 + 7 * ----> Store this in an array of strings.

```
String arrayOfStrings[];
arrayOfStrings = inputString.split(" ")
```

String 1 = 10

String 2 = 3

String 3 = +

String 4 = 7

String 5 = *

I think you should insert it as strings instead of individual characters.

Comment: Okay so are you saying something like insert(arrayOfStrings[i])?

Comment: Yes right. You can pass the string to the insert method. And if you want are still more comfortable with characters,  you may use string.charAt(index) method on the tokenized string.